# Multi column pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I want to pivot some tables but I want to do it from several column and rename each new column correctly

Having this table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCo0X.png)

And I want something like this, I want to do it in a very large table so I need the names to assign automatically

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIy0L.png)

I have tried the normal pivot but it only works for one column

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a WIDE table, this will "dynamically" unpivot your data and then `PIVOT` the temporary results

**Example**

```
Select A.[Name]
      ,Item = concat([key],'_',[year])
      ,Value = try_convert(int,B.Value)
 Into  #Temp
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply  (
                 Select [Key]
                       ,Value
                 From OpenJson(  (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )  ) 
                 Where [Key] not in ('Name','year')
              ) B

Declare @Cols varchar(max) = (Select string_agg(item,',') from ( Select item from #Temp group by item ) A)

Declare @SQL  varchar(max)= '
Select *
 From #Temp A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in (' + @Cols  + ') ) p
'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Results**

[image]

**For Comparison**

```
Name    math_1  math_2  statistics_1    statistics_2
jhon    90      50      100             65
maria   85      89      89              68
pedro   60      70      87              79
```

Comment: You'd be setting a better example to question asker's if you didn't use images in answers also. They don't look any better on mobil devices in dark mode in answers as they do in questions 

Comment: @DaleK A perfectly valid point.   However, in my opinion, it is a quick visual confirming desired results.  Also, I think the display on mobile devices is perfectly fine (I'm team Dark Mode).   Just for fun, I added the text results, I still think the image is better.    It would be fun to poll this... I've been wrong before and I'll certainly be wrong again.

Comment: I think the text view is much better. But it's more about encouraging new posters to post their sample data as text